# Geopandas - plot points with their IDs

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, point, geopandas

I would like to paint on a map a list of points with the id of each point next to it, this is what I am doing

```
dfPoints["id"] = dfPoints.index
geomertrySensores2 = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(dfPoints['longitud'], dfPoints['latitud'])]
crs =  {'int':'epsg:4326'}
geoSensores = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dfPoints,crs=crs, geometry = geomertrySensores2)

# creating color map for categories
categories = np.unique(geoSensores["id"])
colors = np.linspace(0, 1, len(categories))
colordict = dict(zip(categories, colors))
geoSensores["Color"] = geoSensores["id"].apply(lambda x: colordict[x])


f, ax = pl.subplots(figsize=(20,15))

geoBase.plot(color = 'grey', alpha=0.4, ax = ax)
geoSensores.plot(ax=ax, markersize=20, color="blue", marker="o", column='id')
```

But I can't add the id of each point on the map
How would be the way to do it?
I have 255 points, so I would like to paint the id of each point next to it and not use color palette

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this using matplotlib:

```
f, ax = pl.subplots(figsize=(120,90))

geoVias.plot(color = 'grey', alpha=0.4, ax = ax)
geoSensores.plot(ax=ax, markersize=20, color="blue", marker="o", column='id')

for  index, row in geoSensores.iterrows():
        x = row.geometry.centroid.x
        y = row.geometry.centroid.y
        pl.text(x, y, row.id, fontsize=10)
```

but the map was very saturated, so I used bokeh which allows zooming

```
p = figure(title="Ubicacion de sensores",
           plot_height = 700 ,
           plot_width = 900, )

def getPointCoords(row, geom, coord_type):
    """Calculates coordinates ('x' or 'y') of a Point geometry"""
    if coord_type == 'x':
        return row[geom].x
    elif coord_type == 'y':
        return row[geom].y
    
ubicacionSensores['x'] = ubicacionSensores.apply(getPointCoords, geom='geometry', coord_type='x', axis=1)
ubicacionSensores['y'] = ubicacionSensores.apply(getPointCoords, geom='geometry', coord_type='y', axis=1)
p_df = geoSensores.drop('geometry', axis=1).copy()   
psource = ColumnDataSource(p_df)   
p.circle('x', 'y', source=psource, color='red', size=7)

my_hover = HoverTool()
my_hover.tooltips = [('Sensor id', '@id')]
p.add_tools(my_hover)
    

def getLineCoords(row, geom, coord_type):
    """Returns a list of coordinates ('x' or 'y') of a LineString geometry"""
    if coord_type == 'x':
        return list( row[geom].coords.xy[0] )
    elif coord_type == 'y':
        return list( row[geom].coords.xy[1] )


geoVias['x'] = geoVias.apply(getLineCoords, geom='geometry', coord_type='x', axis=1)
geoVias['y'] = geoVias.apply(getLineCoords, geom='geometry', coord_type='y', axis=1)
m_df = geoVias.drop('geometry', axis=1).copy()
msource = ColumnDataSource(m_df)
p.multi_line('x', 'y', source=msource, color='grey', alpha=0.4, line_width=1)

show(p)
```